# Enable spamassassin only for certain domains

Tags: postfix, dovecot, spamassassin, amavis

I have a postfix/dovecot/spamassassin mail server with virtual users on mysql. The server have more than one domain.

I need a way to leave disabled spammassassin by default and enable it only for certain domains.

I am confused and I do not know if it can be done and what would be the correct way

Comment: How has spamassassin been hooked into your config? If its using a script (which is not uncommon), you could always modify that script to conditionally pipe through spamassassin depending on sender/receiver domain?

Comment: Basically I only descommented the amavis lines and It works. But my mind is opened to other configurations.